# Declare template without parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to declare a template without parameters?

I have a template like:

```
template < int i, int j>
class X{
     int  doSomething() { return i+j;}
}
```

and now i want to use this Template in another class, but i don't know its parameter cause they are variable. But i would like to save different templates in a variable like this :

```
class Foo {
X        var;

void setVar ( const X &newVar) { var = newVar;  }
X    getVar () { return var;}
}
```

Is there a way to save different types of the template in one variable ? or pointer ?

Thx for help

Comment: Templates are a compile-time thing, so unless you know at least all the possible values of i and j at compile-time then the answer is no.

Comment: Yeah i was afraid that this will be the answer -.- but thanks ;)

Comment: Or, you can make `Foo` itself a template...

Comment: That will only shift the problem to the next class which uses Foo.

Comment: Or you can use type erasure

Comment: @J.W.: If you're concerned about "shifting the problem", odds are that `X` should have variables instead of templates.

Comment: This is not a use case for templates in any shape or form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Templates are resolved at compile time; your template parameters can't depend on values that aren't known until runtime.  Furthermore, each instance of a template is a different type:  `X<1, 2>` and `X<3, 4>` are different just like two classes `Foo` and `Bar` are different; a variable of the one type can't hold a value of the other.  You can't have a variable whose type is just `X`, because `X` is not a type (it's a template).

It doesn't make sense for a template to have no parameters; you don't need a template at all in that case.  It's not clear why you're trying to use templates to add two variables.  You probably want to just use a class that holds two integers passed to its constructor:

```
class X {
private:
    int i, j;

public:
    X(int i, int j): i(i), j(j) { }

    int doSomething() const { return i + j; }
};
```

This will let you have variables of type `X`, and you can construct different instances of `X` with different values for `i` and `j` based on variables at runtime.

Comment: The method do something was just a fill, its not the real function. I hoped that there was a way -.- but the parameters arent known at buildtime so i guess i have to find another way. actually i was trying to build some SIUnit api, and therefore the every int representing one SI value like m² -> m=2  and so on. ( I know there is a boost implementation, but there is the same problem), anyway thr for answer ;)

Comment: @J.W.: If the parameters aren't known at buildtime, then templates are 100% the wrong tool.  Use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use type erasure. [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/basic.html) provides a good implementation which might suffice for your use case. Here's the example from there modified for your situation :

```
BOOST_TYPE_ERASURE_MEMBER((canDoSomething), doSomething, 0)

class Foo {
using X = any<canDoSomething<int(void)>>;
X        var;

void setVar ( const X &newVar) { var = newVar;  }
X    getVar () { return var;}
int DoSomethingWithX() { return var.doSomething();}
}
```